# Is it possible to have multiple views use one model but have all input go to the same table?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm playing around with user inputs in a madlib game, I want the user to be able to fill out the blanks then play a second game that would remember the first inputs. I have one model that handles all of the inputs, the user is asked to fill out forms on different pages but instead of appending their inputs into the same table it creates a new one. I feel like it has something to do with my views but I'm not sure how to send everything to one table, I'll post my views below.

```
from .models import Story
from .forms import PartOneForm, PartTwoForm

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'mad_libs/index.html')

def story(request):
"""Show part one"""
    story = Story.objects.all()
    context = {'story': story}
    return render(request, 'mad_libs/part_one.html', context)

def part_one_forms(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = PartOneForm()
    else:
        form = PartOneForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('mad_libs:part_one')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'mad_libs/part_one_forms.html', context)

def story_2(request):
"""Show part one"""
    story = Story.objects.all()
    context = {'story': story}
    return render(request, 'mad_libs/part_two.html', context)

def part_two_forms(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = PartTwoForm()
    else:
        form = PartTwoForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('mad_libs:part_two')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'mad_libs/part_two_forms.html', context)
```

Comment: Please add your model, and your forms classes.

Comment: As per my understanding, two rows are created when user submits partoneform and parttwoform, that is because form.save() in 'part_two_forms' view creates a new record by default, if all the fields are given valid input or have default values. If you want to use the same row that has been created in 'part_one_forms' view in 'part_two_forms' view, you have to override the save method in your Form classes. Make sure you get the row that has been already created and update/append the new values recieved. This might help you - https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-forms-basics/